# Roles/Permissions - can caching affect it?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-mvc-2

Once authenticatated I use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` to ensure user is authorized to view a part of my site.

When I access certain parts of my site I need to get the User and get which context (organization they are logged into), **url** would be something like `settings/supercompany/profile`. where *supercompany* is the current context.

For each user I would need to check if they are admin in that company or a general user, if a general user then they cannot see certain things.

```
public class SettingsApi
{
    private readonly string _userId;
    private readonly string _contextId;

    public SettingsApi(string userId, string contextId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
        _contextId = contextId;
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the class above from a controller (post or get), would caching somehow mess things up? Users role changed and I don't pick it up? Would something like the below work well?

```
var settings = new SettingsApi(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, currentContextId);
settings.IsAdmin();
```

Note: I would have used attributes to authorize but my requirements are I need to pick out the currentContext from the URL plus I need to use the class above elsewhere in my code.

**Update**

*AuthorizeAttribute* works well with caching, but the method used to authorize i.e.

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

Will not hand me back an instance of the class I need...

**Update 2** I don't want this class or an instance of this class to be cached in anyway, everytime I ask for a new instance I don't mind fetching one from the DB...

My Question - is the way I am coding ok? Will my user and his permissions NOT be cached?

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but have a look at MSDN about disabling caching in the role provider. Disabling it will mean that when you use the likes of Authorize(Roles="Admin") that your check will be carried out every request - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.cacherolesincookie.aspx

Comment: I think that's what I really want to be honest with you - this is something I don't really want to cache just yet. Besides I will probably build an optimized, custom caching facility myself around some core parts of my system. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you're not careful, to let MVC cache the output of the first request by an authenticated user. I use VaryByCustom and the current identity's name.

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom="user")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
  // etc.
}
```

In my Global.asax.cs I define:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom.Equals("user", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? context.User.Identity.Name : string.Empty;
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Comment: Would the above allow me *Not* to cache an instance of this class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are proposing to add  instances of the SettingsApi to the cache then it definitely will not work as caching is app wide and so all users will end up sharing the same SettingsApi. Using the OutputCache should be fine (as long as you dont do something like put userid in a hidden field and use  [OutputCache(VaryByCustom="user")] or similar).

If you are looking to cache the SettingsApi you should do so through SessionState which is per user/session and wont affect the authentication.